# Add custom ID to CPT posts only create not update

Tags: custom-post-types, plugin-development, advanced-custom-fields

I'm trying to autofill a custom field only when the post is created and not when it is updated.

CPT "valoraciones"
ACF custom fields "ID_valoraciones".

The ID_valoraciones is an incremental number. That is, for post 1, ID_valoraciones: 1, post 2, ID_valoraciones: 2 and so on ...

So far I have the following action:

```
           function auto_assign_ids( $post_id, $post, $update ) {

        // Only assign ID to new approved "valoraciones" posts
        if ( $post->post_status == 'publish' && $post->post_type == 'valoraciones' ) {
       
            // get the most recent "valoraciones" posts
            $valoracion_args = array(
                'numberposts'       =>   2,
                'post_type'         =>   'valoraciones',
                'orderby'           =>   'post_date',
                'order'             =>   'DESC'
            );
            $valoraciones = get_posts( $valoracion_args );
       
            // get the id_valoraciones of the prior post
            $last_id = get_post_meta( $valoraciones[1]->ID, 'id_valoraciones', true );
       
            // increment
            if ( !$last_id ) {
                $last_id = 0;
            }       
             $last_id++;
            
                // unhook this function so it doesn't loop infinitely
                remove_action( 'save_post', 'auto_assign_ids', 10, 3 );
                // set the id_valoraciones of the current post
                update_post_meta( $post_id, 'id_valoraciones', $last_id );
                // re-hook this function
                add_action( 'save_post', 'auto_assign_ids', 10, 3 );
        }
        
 
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'auto_assign_ids', 10, 3 );
```

Every time I update a post, it modifies the value of the "id_valoraciones", is there any way so that once it is created it does not modify that value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's simple - check for existence of `id_valoraciones` meta value when saving post. If post does not have `id_valoraciones` set, do your job with getting last value and incerementing it. If the post has `id_valoraciones` meta, then - do nothing. Like this:

```
<?php
function auto_assign_ids( $post_id, $post, $update ) {

    // Only assign ID to new approved "valoraciones" posts
    if ( $post->post_status == 'publish' && $post->post_type == 'valoraciones' ) {
                
        $id_valoraciones = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'id_valoraciones', true );
        
        if( ! $id_valoraciones ) {
            
            // get the most recent "valoraciones" posts
            $valoracion_args = array(
            'numberposts'       =>   2,
            'post_type'         =>   'valoraciones',
            'orderby'           =>   'post_date',
            'order'             =>   'DESC'
            );
            $valoraciones = get_posts( $valoracion_args );

            // get the id_valoraciones of the prior post
            $last_id = get_post_meta( $valoraciones[1]->ID, 'id_valoraciones', true );

            // increment
            if ( !$last_id ) {
                $last_id = 0;
            }       
            
            $last_id++;
            
            update_post_meta( $post_id, 'id_valoraciones', $last_id );
            
        } else {
            
            // id_valoraciones was set before
            
        }
        
    }
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'auto_assign_ids', 100, 3 );
```

By the way, `remove_action` part of your code is useless, `update_post_meta` does not trigger `save_post` hook, it's used when `wp_insert_post()`ing inside `save_post` hook.